# I want to get difference of sum of a column from two tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: transactions and transactions_archive. Each of them has fields accountno,drcr(which has values either as C or D) and field amount. I want to get difference of sum of all 'C' in both transactions and transactions_archive and sum of all 'D' in both transactions and transactions_archive.
What query can I use to get this answer.

I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
    select (
        select accountno,drcr,sum(amount)as total from
        (
            select accountno,drcr,amount 
              from ebank.tbtransactions 
             where drcr='C'
         union all
            select accountno,drcr,amount 
              from ebank.tbtransactions_archive 
             where drcr='C'
        )
    )
    -
    (select accountno,drcr,sum(amount)as total 
       from (
           select accountno,drcr,amount 
             from ebank.tbtransactions 
            where drcr='D'
        union all
           select accountno,drcr,amount 
             from ebank.tbtransactions_archive 
            where drcr='D'
        )
    )
    group by accountno,drcr;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to subtract all the "D"s from the "C"s.  Combine the tables using `UNION ALL` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select accountno,
       sum(case when drcr = 'C' then amount else - amount end)as total
from ((select accountno, drcr, amount
       from ebank.tbtransactions
      ) union all
      (select accountno, drcr, amount
       from ebank.tbtransactions_archive
      ) 
     ) t
where drcr in ('D', 'C')
group by accountno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 (amount - nextamount) as diff from(
SELECT
    amount,LEAD(amount, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(drcr)) AS nextamount  FROM(
SELECT drcr, sum(amount) as amount from transactions JOIN transactions_archive on transactions.drcr and transactions_archive.drcr GROUP BY drcr))
```